# Stripping ContextPath in WebFlux router?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, contextpath

I have a WebFlux application that is behind `nginx-ingress`.

In order to have redirect working (for purposes of Spring Security OAuth) I enabled `ForwardedHeaderTransformer`.

Now redirects generated by Spring Security OAuth are working fine, but the problem arises when I want to access my API exposed by `RouterFunction`s.

For instance I have an endpoint `GET /someresource`. When request is made `ForwardedHeaderTransformer` adds `/api/myservice` both to `contextPath` and `uri`.

Question is how to expose my api without adding `/api/myservice` to router function?

Is there any (clean) option to strip `contextPath` (if it's present) and serve API like this:

```
fun router() = router {

    "/someresource".nest {

        GET("/", myHandler::getResource)

        GET("/{id}", myHandler::getResources)
```

Maybe there is a `WebFilter` that can be triggered just before `RouterFunction`s or maybe it can be modified in the other way?

I've tried to add `HandlerFilterFunction` to my router. But it does not work since there is no mapping for `/api/myservice` registered.

Comment: I've added PR that will cover my use case: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/22785